# java.lang.IllegalStateException while using ViewPager in Android

Tags: java, android

I have a ViewPager which is a part of a popup window. When I open a popup window for the first time, everything works well, but when I open it for the second time with the same data, I have a IllegalStateException error.

Here is a stack trace:

> 04-08 15:17:48.370: E/AndroidRuntime(10929): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   04-08 15:17:48.370: E/AndroidRuntime(10929):
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a
>   parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first. 04-08
>   15:17:48.370: E/AndroidRuntime(10929):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3337) 04-08
>   15:17:48.370: E/AndroidRuntime(10929):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3208) 04-08
>   15:17:48.370: E/AndroidRuntime(10929):    at
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addView(ViewPager.java:920) 04-08
>   15:17:48.370: E/AndroidRuntime(10929):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3165) 04-08
>   15:17:48.370: E/AndroidRuntime(10929):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3145) 04-08
>   15:17:48.370: E/AndroidRuntime(10929):    at
>   com.componentix.imwizard.SamplePagerAdapter.instantiateItem(SamplePagerAdapter.java:22)
>   04-08 15:17:48.370: E/AndroidRuntime(10929):  at
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:649) 04-08
>   15:17:48.370: E/AndroidRuntime(10929):    at
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:783) 04-08
>   15:17:48.370: E/AndroidRuntime(10929):    at
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.completeScroll(ViewPager.java:1280)
>   04-08 15:17:48.370: E/AndroidRuntime(10929):  at
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.computeScroll(ViewPager.java:1176)
>   04-08 15:17:48.370: E/AndroidRuntime(10929):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2729) 04-08
>   15:17:48.370: E/AndroidRuntime(10929):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489) 04-08
>   15:17:48.370: E/AndroidRuntime(10929):    at
>   android.view.View.buildDrawingCache(View.java:10693) 04-08
>   15:17:48.370: E/AndroidRuntime(10929):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2747) 04-08
>   15:17:48.370: E/AndroidRuntime(10929):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489) 04-08
>   15:17:48.370: E/AndroidRuntime(10929):    at
>   android.view.View.draw(View.java:10981) 04-08 15:17:48.370:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(10929):  at
>   android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10417) 04-08 15:17:48.370:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(10929):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2597)
>   04-08 15:17:48.370: E/AndroidRuntime(10929):  at
>   android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10380) 04-08 15:17:48.370:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(10929):  at
>   android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:842)
>   04-08 15:17:48.370: E/AndroidRuntime(10929):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:1910) 04-08
>   15:17:48.370: E/AndroidRuntime(10929):    at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1634)
>   04-08 15:17:48.370: E/AndroidRuntime(10929):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442) 04-08
>   15:17:48.370: E/AndroidRuntime(10929):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 04-08
>   15:17:48.370: E/AndroidRuntime(10929):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 04-08 15:17:48.370:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(10929):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4430) 04-08
>   15:17:48.370: E/AndroidRuntime(10929):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 04-08
>   15:17:48.370: E/AndroidRuntime(10929):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 04-08 15:17:48.370:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(10929):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
>   04-08 15:17:48.370: E/AndroidRuntime(10929):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:559) 04-08
>   15:17:48.370: E/AndroidRuntime(10929):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Here is my code:

```
public void showPopupWindow(Drawable picture)
{
    int imageResource = R.drawable.background;
    Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
    popupLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
    popupLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    popupLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background);
    LayoutInflater ltInflater = getLayoutInflater();
    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)ltInflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_layout, null);
    PagerContainer pagerContainer = (PagerContainer)(rl.getChildAt(0));
    CirclePageIndicator circlePageIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator)(rl.getChildAt(1));
    Button button = (Button)(rl.getChildAt(2));

    int maxWidth = 1;
    int maxHeight = 1;
    for (Drawable drawable: bigImages) {
        Bitmap bmp = drawableToBitmap(drawable);
        maxWidth = Math.max(maxWidth, bmp.getWidth());
        maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, bmp.getHeight());
    }

    ViewPager viewPager = pagerContainer.getViewPager();
    //viewPager.setBackgroundDrawable(image);

    ArrayList<ImageView> tmpImageViewsWithScreenshots = (ArrayList<ImageView>) imageViewsWithScreenshots.clone();
    SamplePagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new SamplePagerAdapter(tmpImageViewsWithScreenshots);
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(imageIndex);
    circlePageIndicator.setViewPager(viewPager);
    circlePageIndicator.setCurrentItem(imageIndex);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int childCount = checkboxLayout.getChildCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < childCount; ++i) {
                RelativeLayout currentLayout = (RelativeLayout) checkboxLayout
                        .getChildAt(i);
                int innerChildCount = currentLayout
                        .getChildCount();
                for (int j = 0; j < innerChildCount; ++j) {
                    View view = currentLayout.getChildAt(j);
                    view.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
            imageViewLayout.setEnabled(true);
            lockableScrollView.setmScrollable(true);
            back.setEnabled(true);
            next.setEnabled(true);
            popupWindow.dismiss();
        }
    });
    popupLayout.addView(rl);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams nlp= new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(450, 600);
    rl.setLayoutParams(nlp);
    popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupLayout,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    int childCount = checkboxLayout.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; ++i) {
        RelativeLayout currentLayout = (RelativeLayout) checkboxLayout
                .getChildAt(i);
        int innerChildCount = currentLayout.getChildCount();
        for (int j = 0; j < innerChildCount; ++j) {
            View view = currentLayout.getChildAt(j);
            view.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
    next.setEnabled(false);
    back.setEnabled(false);
    imageViewLayout.setEnabled(false);
    lockableScrollView.setmScrollable(false);
    popupWindow
            .showAtLocation(mainLayout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    }
```

And here is code of my adapter:

```
public class SamplePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

    List<ImageView> pages = null;

    public SamplePagerAdapter(List<ImageView> pages){
        this.pages = pages;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position){
        View v = pages.get(position);
        //((ViewPager) collection).addView(v, 0);
        container.addView(v);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object){
        container.removeView((View)object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return pages.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object){
        return view.equals(object);
    }

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: try this way `@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {return view == ((View) object);}` in your `SamplePagerAdapter`

Comment: @SimplePlan Still doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that in your adapters method `instantiateItem`
you call `container.addView(v);`

but every `View` can have only one parent,
so it can be added only one time to a container via `addView(...)`.

When you open the popup the first time, everything works, because `v`
doesn't have a parent that time. But when you open your popupwinow the second time,
it adds the view again to the container. That cerates the error.

Try to destroy the view if you close the popup view or remove all children views from it with
[`container.removeAllViews()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeAllViews%28%29)

it should work then.

Comment: Yes, I think so, but how can I fix this?

Comment: Yes, thank you, your solution works.  
ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) v.getParent();
        if (parent != null) {
         parent.removeAllViews();
        }

Answer (score 2):

The problem is when you add  View v in  container.addView(v) for second time.

I've found the solution  adding this:

```
        if(v.getParent()!=null)
        ((ViewGroup)v.getParent()).removeView(v);
```

before container.addView(v)